# Qual o formato básico de uma rede convolucional no keras?

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Atualmente estudo sobre redes neurais no Keras e não consigo entender como monta a estrutura básica da rede, como estou no ensino médio fica muito difícil eu aprender o avançado sem nenhuma formação na área.

Entendo um pouco sobre a teoria das redes convolucionais, o que eu não consigo fazer é a estrutura, ou o modelo sofre "overfitting" ou "underfitting".

Segue abaixo uma das redes que tentei fazer(ela esta sofrendo underfitting)

OBS: Imagens usadas com as dimensões de 64x64

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))
                                  #pool_size = quadrado q ira somar  # Strides = pulo
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta é muito relevante, e é um dos grandes desafios de trabalhar com redes neurais. Não se preocupe com estar no ensino médio, essa dificuldade é a mesma pra todo mundo!

Se o seu modelo está com 'underfitting', quer dizer que está faltando ao modelo a capacidade para capturar os padrões do conjunto de treinamento. Algumas formas de aumentar a capacidade são adicionar mais camadas ou criar camadas com mais unidades (ou filtros, para CNNs). Não tem exatamente uma regra do que priorizar, então você tem mesmo é que experimentar várias configurações para encontrar a que tem melhor performance **para o seu problema**.

Um padrão que parece ser constante para CNNs é que, a cada camada, a quantidade de filtros aumenta e o tamanho da imagem diminui (exatamente como você fez no seu código).

Algumas dicas que podem ajudar:

- Leia [este artigo](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/).
- Releia o artigo acima.
- Aumente a capacidade do modelo até chegar em uma condição overfitting (indicando que seu modelo tem capacidade para representar o fenômeno). Experimente adicionar camadas ou variar a quantidade de unidades/filtros em cada camada. Meça o resultado monitorando o erro **no conjunto de treinamento**.
- Considere o uso de GPUs para reduzir o tempo de treinamento e te dar a chance de experimentar mais configurações e arquiteturas diferentes em menos tempo. Você pode rodar um jupyter notebook com GPU gratuitamente com o [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). Só seguir o link, criar ou abrir um notebook, clicar em Runtime -> Change runtime type e escolher GPU.
- Quando chegar na condição de overfitting, tente reduzi-la adicionando dropout ou regularização L2. Ajuste os parâmetros de maneira a reduzir o erro **no conjunto de validação**.
- Veja na [documentação do keras](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) os callbacks disponíveis. Tem uma resposta acima sugerindo o *ModelCheckpoint*, que é bem útil. Mas considere também o *EarlyStopping* (termina o processo de treinamento quando identifica overfitting) e o *ReduceLROnPlateau* (reduz o learning rate quando identifica que sua perda no conjunto de validação não está melhorando).
- Quando chamar o método fit(), atribua o resultado a uma variável *history*, que vai receber uma lista com os resultados das perdas e métricas de treinamento e validação. Use *matplotlib* para plotar os gráficos e pegar uma intuição sobre o andamento do processo de treinamento. Algo assim:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
history = model.fit(.....)     
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])     
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])     
plt.show()
```

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Maneiras de se evitar overfitting.

1 - Ná hora de separar os seus dados os separe em 3 partes. train,val e test.
os dados de testes serão para teste.
os dados de val são usadas para se ver o desempenho da rede enquanto treina.
os dados de teste são utilizados para o teste final.
Essa etapa é feita na preparação dos dados.

2 - Segue abaixo um código que vc pode acrescentar ao seu script para evitar overffiting.

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

mc = ModelCheckpoint('auto_encouder.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
# Train the model
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=1000 // batch_size,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=1000 // batch_size)
```

Repare no parâmetro monitor que utilizo o val_loss para salvar a melhor rede durante o tempo. Isso irá garantir uma rede mais genérica.
Porem o que vai te fazer ter uma rede otimizada ao máximo é tempo de dedicação ao estudo de seu dataset e das diferentes arquiteturas utilizadas para treino.